# Using Javascript (no jquery) to append data from 2 json strings - append is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, forms

I have formdata i stringify that looks like this

```
{"name":"jack miller", "address":"123 main st"}
```

I want to append more records but i was getting "append is not a function"

goal to have this      {"name":"jack miller", "address":"123 main st"}, {"name":"new guy", "address":"new address"}

```
const s = this hold master data
const data = new FormData(e.target);
let m = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data));

let c = s.concat(m)  // concat doesn't include a comma 
let d = s.append(m)  // append throw error of  append is not a function
```

So while i tend to have json strings, i could convert to object or array and then back if that is better or easier to append etc..

Why doesn't append work?

Update:   There is jsfiddle of the formdata   https://jsfiddle.net/fx6ebaj5

That "m" is what i need to add data to.

Comment: What is the data type of `s`? Arrays in JS use `.push`, not `.append` if that helps.

Comment: Type of `s` is important for us to tell why is it not working so can you do a `typeof(s)` and update in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to add objects to array**

```
let arr = [{"name":"jack miller", "address":"123 main st"} 
];
```

without modifying actual array

```
let obj = {"name":"John", "address":"432 main st"} 
let newArr = [...arr, obj];
console.log(newArr);

let appendArr=arr.concat(obj)
console.log(appendArr);
```

modified actual array

```
arr.push(obj)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I commented on question and added this jsfiddle   `m` is the formdata and push it doesn't like      https://jsfiddle.net/fx6ebaj5

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of copying an object in Javascript. One is shallow copying and another one is deep copying. The best way to copy an object would be to deep copy the 
feature as it would not affect the changes made to the copied one.

`JSON.stringify turns an object into a string.`
`JSON.parse turns a string into an object.`

Combining them can turn an object into a string, and then reverse the process to create a brand new data structure.

```
nestedObject = [
 {"name":"jack miller", "address":"123 main st"},
 {"name":"jon", "address":"13 main st"}];

numbersCopy = JSON.parse(
JSON.stringify(nestedNumbers)
);

numbersCopy.push({"name":"Shawn", "address":"13 main st"});
console.log(nestedObject, numbersCopy);

[
 {"name":"jack miller", "address":"123 main st"},
 {"name":"jon", "address":"13 main st"}
];

[
 {"name":"jack miller", "address":"123 main st"},
 {"name":"jon", "address":"13 main st"},
 {"name":"Shawn", "address":"13 main st"}
];

// These two arrays are completely separate!
```

So in your case to convert `m` as per your requirement, I would do below steps

```
const m = {hello: "hello", hi: "hi"}
let mArray = []

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(m)) {
  let obj = {}
  obj.key = value
  mArray.push(obj)
}

mArray.push({"name":"Shawn", "address":"13 main st"})
```

So I am converting your `m` object to an array. It should work now.

Comment: Here is my issue,  i'm not using jquery, but in this i have a formdata form submit example of what i'm trying to do .    this jsfiddle works to do a push with your data but not with mine       https://jsfiddle.net/fx6ebaj5

Comment: Notice that `let m` is what i'm trying to do with formdata, and so `m.push` is saying  its not a function.   the other stuff of yours works with arr / obj  ...   i need to be able to work with the formdata

Comment: `m.push` is not working because m is an object and the `push` method is available only on `array`. So in your case, you need to use. Object.entries() to convert an object to an array.

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your need, please check that.